# How to render anti-aliased image to a texture (and then write to PNG)?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, render-to-texture, multisampling

I'd like to use the "render to texture" paradigm to write a .png screenshot of my OpenGL 3D rendering. I have it working *without* multi-sampling, but I'm struggling to get an anti-aliased image.

First of all, is this possible?

Second, what is the right combination of API calls?

(meta third question, how can I better debug this? `glCheckFramebufferStatus` is clearly not enough).

Here's what I'm working with:

```
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402504/multisampled-render-to-texture-in-ios
  GLuint texture;
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA4, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  GLuint resolved_framebuffer, resolvedColorRenderbuffer;
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &resolved_framebuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, resolved_framebuffer);
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &resolvedColorRenderbuffer);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, resolvedColorRenderbuffer);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

  assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

  GLuint framebuffer;
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

  GLuint colorRenderbuffer, depthRenderbuffer;
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
  glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
  glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);


  assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

  glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );
  glClearColor(background_color(0), background_color(1), background_color(2), 0.f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);// | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  draw_scene();

  glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer );
  glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, resolved_framebuffer );
  // https://forum.juce.com/t/ios-8-getting-the-demo-building/13570/20
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
  // ^--- this is throwing `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`


  GLubyte* pixels = (GLubyte*)calloc(width*height*4,sizeof(GLubyte));
  glReadPixels(0, 0,width, height,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

  writePNG(pixels);
```

Currently I'm getting a blank image and `glBlitFramebuffer` is throwing `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Apparently [this error can correspond to many things](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml), and I'm not sure which is applying. My buffers seem "good" according to `glCheckFramebufferStatus`.

This question has been asked in similar forms before:

- [Cannot render to texture with multisampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072447/cannot-render-to-texture-with-multisampling)
- [Multisampled render to texture in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402504/multisampled-render-to-texture-in-ios)

But none of the answers have lead to a complete working example. I would love to find/create a *minimal* example of this.

Comment: I tried removing the `resolvedColorRenderbuffer` and corresponding lines. But this fails in the same way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Good tuto [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)

Comment: I tried removing `resolvedColorRenderbuffer` altogether, so that `resolved_framebuffer` is just attached to `texture` via the `    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);` line. Is that correct? (still not working)

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial at https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Anti-Aliasing basically had what I needed. The working solution is:

```
  unsigned int framebuffer;
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  // create a multisampled color attachment texture
  unsigned int textureColorBufferMultiSampled;
  glGenTextures(1, &textureColorBufferMultiSampled);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureColorBufferMultiSampled);
  glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGBA, width, height, GL_TRUE);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureColorBufferMultiSampled, 0);
  // create a (also multisampled) renderbuffer object for depth and stencil attachments
  unsigned int rbo;
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
  glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
  assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

  // configure second post-processing framebuffer
  unsigned int intermediateFBO;
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &intermediateFBO);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, intermediateFBO);
  // create a color attachment texture
  unsigned int screenTexture;
  glGenTextures(1, &screenTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTexture);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTexture, 0);    // we only need a color buffer
  assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

  draw_scene();

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, intermediateFBO);
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, intermediateFBO);
  GLubyte* pixels = (GLubyte*)calloc(width*height*4,sizeof(GLubyte));
  glReadPixels(0, 0,width, height,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

  writePNG(pixels);
```

It seems there're at least two errors in the code in the original question:

1. The `framebuffer` should have a multisample *texture* attached, not a renderbuffer (`glFramebufferTexture2D(... GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` instead of `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample`)
2. Must call `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, intermediateFBO);` after blitting and before `glReadPixels`